# String literal in templates - different behavior of compilers

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

Suppose we have the following code:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(const T&);

int main()
{
   foo("str");
}
```

[Demonstration](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4Gagz0%240)

**gcc 4.7.2, clang 3.2, icc 13.0.1**

> undefined reference to `void foo<**char** [4]>(char const (&) [4])'

**MSVC-11.0**

> unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl foo<**char const** [4]>(char
>   const (&)[4])" (??$foo@$$BY03$$CBD@@YAXAAY03$$CBD@Z)

Notice `char[4]` in the first output and `char const[4]` in the second output.

Why? And who's right? Can you quote the standard, please?

Comment: both are complaining there is no `foo` defined....

Comment: @UmNyobe Yes, i know, it was needed to print type only

Comment: @UmNyobe I mean what type should be in this case - char[4] or char const[4]?

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov: That's a good question, without the array it's pretty trivial, but with I am not sure where the `const` should appear (if at all).

Comment: my guess is that MSVC is just doing additional work.

Comment: My intuition says that gcc is correct, since the `const` is applied to the `T` and not part of it. Let's find out...

Comment: The rule in C was always that there is no such thing as a const array; const applied to an array type propagated down to the elements of the array.  I'm not sure about C++, however (and it could make a difference here).  And of course, does this propagation down occur before or after the type has beeen resolved.

Comment: The final result is: is the actual parameter type after template type deduction `char const[4] const` (which can't exist otherwise), or does the const in the template declaration propagate down to the array elements, giving `char const[4]`.  In the first case, the instantiation type is `char const[4]`, and in the second, `char[4]`.  I can think of good arguments both ways, but I'd like to see an answer with some justification from the standard to back it up.

Comment: How does MSVC behave if you pass an actual `char` array?  What if you pass a `const char` array? http://liveworkspace.org/code/pMSFp$1

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov: My answer should clarify things

Answer (score 5):

**GCC is right.**

Let's start from a slightly simpler example, and later prove that the original example follows the same pattern:

```
template<typename T>
void bar(T const&)
{
    // Shall not fire
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, int>::value, "Error!");
}

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    bar(x); // 1 - Assertion won't fire

    int const y = 0;
    bar(y); // 2 - Assertion won't fire
}
```

What's happening here? First of all, per § 14.8.2.1/3:

> [...] If P is a reference type, the type referred to by P is used for type deduction. [...]

This means that type deduction will try to match `T const` against `int` (in case 1) and against `int const` (in case 2). In the second case, substituting `int` for `T` will yield a perfect match, so that's easy; in the first case, we have the `const` getting on our way to have a perfect match. But this is where § 14.8.2.1/4 comes into play:

> [...] **If the original P is a reference type**, the deduced A (i.e., the type referred to by the reference) **can be
>   more cv-qualified** than the transformed A. [...]

Here, replacing `int` for `T` gives us a deduced `int const`, which is more cv-qualified than `int` (the type of the argument `x`). But that is acceptable because of § 14.8.2.1/4 above, so even in this case `T` is deduced to be `int`.

Let's now tackle your original example (just slightly adjusted, but we'll get to the original version eventually):

```
template<typename T>
void bar(T const&)
{
    // Does not fire in GCC, fires in VC11. Who's right?
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, char[4]>::value, "Error!");
}

int main()
{
    char x[] = "foo";
    bar(x);

    char const y[] = "foo";
    bar(y);
}
```

Apart from the fact that I replaced `int` with `char []`, this is example and my first example are identical in structure. To see why this equivalence holds, consider the assertion below (which doesn't fire on *any* compiler, as expected):

```
// Does not fire
static_assert(
    std::is_same<
        std::add_const<char [4]>::type,
        char const[4]
    >::value, "Error");
```

The C++11 Standard mandates this behavior in Paragraph 3.9.3/2:

> Any cv-qualifiers applied to an array type affect the array element type, not the array type (8.3.4).

Paragraph 8.3.4/1 also specifies:

> [...] Any type of the form “cv-qualifier-seq array of N T” is adjusted to “array
>   of N cv-qualifier-seq T”, and similarly for “array of unknown bound of T”. The optional attribute-specifier-seq
>   appertains to the array. [ Example:

```
typedef int A[5], AA[2][3];
typedef const A CA; // type is “array of 5 const int”
typedef const AA CAA; // type is “array of 2 array of 3 const int”
```

> —end example ] [ Note: An “array of N cv-qualifier-seq T” has cv-qualified type; see 3.9.3. —end note ]

Since it is now clear that the two examples exhibit the same pattern, it makes sense to apply the same logic. And that will lead us through the very same reasoning path.

While performing type deduction, `T const` is matched against `char[4]` in the first case and against `char const[4]` in the second case.

In the second case, `T = char[4]` yields a perfect match, because `T const` becomes `char const[4]` after the substitution. In the first case, the deduced `A` is once again more cv-qualified than the original `A`, in that substituting `char[4]` for `T` yields `char const[4]`. But then again, that is allowed by 14.8.2.1/4, so `T` should be deduced as `char[4]`.

Finally, back to your original example. Since the string literal `"str"` also has type `char const[4]`, `T` should be deduced to be `char [4]`, which means that **GCC is right**:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T const&)
{
    // Shall not fire
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, char[4]>::value, "Error!");
}

int main()
{
    foo("str"); // Shall not trigger the assertion
}
```

Comment: But why is `std::add_const<char [4]>::type` the same as `char const[4]`? That does not seem to be obvious - the first is a const array of 4 chars, while the second is an array of 4 const chars.

Comment: @interjay: See 3.9.3/2 of the C++11 Standard: "[...] Any cv-qualifiers applied to an array type affect the array element type, not the array type (8.3.4)."

Comment: @interjay: I expanded a bit on this in the last update to my answer

Answer (score 1):

GCC is correct; that `const` in VS's template argument list should not be there:

> `[C++11: 14.8.2/3]:` After this substitution is performed, the function parameter type adjustments described in 8.3.5 are performed. *[ Example:* A parameter type of `“void ()(const int, int[5])”` becomes `“void(*)(int,int*)”`. *—end example ]* ***[ Note:* A top-level qualifier in a function parameter declaration does not affect the function
>   type but still affects the type of the function parameter variable within the function. *—end note ]*** *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> template <class T> void f(T t);
> template <class X> void g(const X x);
> template <class Z> void h(Z, Z*);
>
> int main() {
>   // #1: function type is f(int), t is non const
>   f<int>(1);
>
>   // #2: function type is f(int), t is const
>   f<const int>(1);
>
>   // #3: function type is g(int), x is const
>   g<int>(1);
>
>   // #4: function type is g(int), x is const
>   g<const int>(1);
>
>   // #5: function type is h(int, const int*)
>   h<const int>(1,0);
> }
> ```
>
> *—end example ]*

(Example 4 is the pertinent one.)

> `[C++11: 14.8.2/5]:` **The resulting substituted and adjusted function type is used as the type of the function template for template argument deduction.** *[..]*

Also possibly relevant:

> **Deducing template arguments from a function call**
>   `[C++11: 14.8.2.1/2]:` If `P` is not a reference type:
>
> - If `A` is an array type, the pointer type produced by the array-to-pointer standard conversion (4.2) is used in place of `A` for type deduction; otherwise,
> - If `A` is a function type, the pointer type produced by the function-to-pointer standard conversion (4.3) is used in place of `A` for type deduction; otherwise,
> - **If `A` is a cv-qualified type, the top level *cv-qualifiers* of `A`’s type are ignored for type deduction**

Comment: We all know this, but how does it apply to the case in question?

Comment: @JamesKanze: The `const` is not part of the function type, and the function type is used for template argument deduction. Thus, `T` in this case shall not be `const`, yet in the OP's example MSVC has made it so. 

Comment: I do think I may be missing a few steps. :( Thought I'd throw it out there, though.

Comment: The `const` *is* part of the function type in the OP's code. The difference between the OP's code and the examples you have given is that in OP's code the function takes a reference to `const`, so the `const` can't be removed.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Where do you see that.  There is no top level const in the OP's code; `int` and `int const` are considered identical types in this context, but `int&` and `int const&` are not.

Comment: @AndyProwl That's quite deliberate - we don't need it to be defined for this demonstration. The point is to _deliberately_ create that error, so that we can examine its _contents_ and find out what the template argument deduction is doing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: You're right, I just misunderstood the whole story.

Comment: I don't quite have this, do I? :( The section on deduction is _too long_ for a quick "while my code's compiling" answer. Someone please use this as a starting point, though!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think you've missed the fact that type deduction works differently when the argument type is a reference.  (For starters, there can be no top level const.)  As for the "while my code's compiling", why do you think I haven't tried to answer?  This is one of the most complicated parts of the C++ standard: it contains a lot of text, with a lot of subtilities which require a lot of thought.  I don't know the actual answer off hand, and I don't have time to analyse the standard either.

Comment: "If P is **not** a reference type" - In this case P is `T const&`.

Comment: @James I'm sorry to hear that. I don't recall ordering you to spend any time on this, though.

Comment: @MSalters Sure you're not confusing `P` with `A`? `Template argument deduction is done by comparing each function template parameter type (call it P) with the type of the corresponding argument of the call (call it A) as described below.`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Unless I'm having a brain failure, A - the argument - is "str" and the type of A is `const char[4]`, and the parameter P is `const T&` (unnamed parameter).

Comment: Oh, guys, so much comments here... Thanks a lot for all of you! But what about the final answer for this question? Do you have a single opinion now?

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov Not even close.